# Unexpected voltage drop in linear dual supply power regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc, linear-regulator, dual-supply

I am attempting to implement a linear dual power regulator circuit using the 7805 and the 7905, as shown below.

It almost works, except that the voltage difference from the ground rail to the positive rail sits at around 4.73 volts instead of the expected 5.

The difference between the ground and the negative rail on the other hand is just as expected, 5 volts and change.

Swapping out the 7805 for a new one changed nothing, nor did raising or lowering the voltage being fed into the circuit, nor changing the values of the capacitors. Could somebody shed some light on what might be happening here?

[image]

Comment: What is `V1`? Your schematic shows `1V`, but I am guessing it is not the case?

Comment: whoops. yeah that's irrelevant, circuit lab threw it in there for me and I neglected to remove it.

Comment: Do you know the 78xx regulator needs 2V higher input then output?

Comment: We need more information. What is the input voltage? Do you have a load (and if so what is it)?

Comment: I've tried input voltages from 14v-20v, and the difference between positive and ground remains the same. There is no load.

Comment: If this instead used a center-tapped transformer as ground (and rectifiers and filter caps) there would be no issue. But with no ground reference, it is being determined by the leakage current of the capacitors.  Hence why +5 is a little low and -5 is a little high.

Comment: It's not unexpected drop. Your circuit lacks common ground potential connection to regulators, so it is an expected drop, as only the regulator quiescent currents define the common potential.

Comment: As an aside, your input side doesn't need 220 nF // 100 nF. I can't say the value to use because I don't know the characteristics of the supply, any cabling and the total load current. I'd expect to see something like 10..100 uF capacitor on each if you're coming from cables.

Comment: Use a centre tapped supply. If the+V supply carries heavier load it'll pull GND up until the  7805 drops out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 0V is floating, it depends on the load ratio or quiescent current ratio of +/- LDO's.  You need to buffer this with a biased Op Amp that can handle much (100x) more current than your single-ended load. Yet OA's tend to be differential loads, so that is not a big issue.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkyPZI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: If you have high load step pulse currents, and Vin was low, then split C3 into 2 separate caps to ground to decouple the inputs better. But I showed the minimum filtering while the linear LDO's will reduce ripple well into the 100 kHz range somewhat reducing due to GBW of internal error amplifier.  So really big uF outputs are only for max currents. Then you may want to add reverse signal diodes to protect against Vout> Vin during turn off.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 & Q2 cater for larger but unequal load currents.

For large currents, heat sinks required for Q1, Q2 and RG1.

[image: PSU]